# Converting ANTLRInputStream to CharStream

Tags: java, antlr4

I have an antlr4 based project with a Main class containing this code:

```
    package com.progur.langtutorial;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;

public class Main {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(args[0]));  

            GYOOLexer lexer = new GYOOLexer(input);
            GYOOParser parser = new GYOOParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
            parser.addParseListener(new MyListener());

            // Start parsing
            parser.program(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

However, since ANTLRInputStream is deprecated, I need to use CharStream instead.
But, when I tried to use CharStream, I cannot move further than,

```
CharStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(args[0]));
```

This is because I do not know how to replace the part of the statement after the '=' sign. I tried `CharStreams.fromFileName(new FileInputStream(args[0]));` but then eclipse states this error "CharStreams.fromFileName cannot be resolved to a type". I also tried `CharStreams.fromFileName(args[0]);` with the same result.
I even tried `CharStream input = new CharStreams.fromFileName("test");` where "test" is the program written to test the language parser that I've written. It was also the same.

I am also having another error in `parser.addParseListener(new MyListener());` where it says `MyListener cannot be resolved to a type`. What could that mean? In every tutorial I looked there was a random name for where 'MyListener()' is.
What should be the correct statement for this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's always a good idea to post error messages. Saying that "it didn't work", tells those willing to help nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I updated my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
CharStream charStream = CharStreams.fromString("test");
```

where `"test"` is the input itself to be parsed.

Or when the input is in a file, do this:

```
CharStream charStream = CharStreams.fromFileName("/path/to/file.ext");
```

If that doesn't work, you  need to inspect the exception that is thrown (most likely the file is not where ANTLR is looking for it: try an absolute path).

Comment: Thanks, it worked! :) But now I'm getting another error which I have included in my question.

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to post a new question for `MyListener cannot be resolved to a type`